# Parsing XML response in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am calling a webservice from Excel macro but not able to parse the response XML. The Structure of the Response is as follows -

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:typ="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracle/apps/marketing/commonMarketing/mktImport/model/types/">
   <env:Header>
      <wsa:Action>http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracle/apps/marketing/commonMarketing/mktImport/model//ImportPublicService/getImportActivityLogsResponse</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:bffbffe9-a379-46bb-8205-7f6b5d15a0f5</wsa:MessageID>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <ns0:getImportActivityLogsResponse xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracle/apps/marketing/commonMarketing/mktImport/model/types/">
         <ns2:result xsi:type="ns1:ImportServiceLogs" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracle/apps/marketing/commonMarketing/mktImport/model/types/" xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oracle/apps/marketing/commonMarketing/mktImport/model/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ns1:LogFileName>log-test_contact_01-02_20150422171310_pverma Data File.csv</ns1:LogFileName>
            <ns1:LogFileContent>
               <xop:Include href="cid:ec277fd6-76e2-4ae3-9e8b-1b14c446adf8" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
            </ns1:LogFileContent>
            <ns1:ErrorLogFileName>error-test_contact_01-02_20150422171310_pverma Data File.csv</ns1:ErrorLogFileName>
            <ns1:ErrorLogFileContent>
               <xop:Include href="cid:d41bacf8-3134-4cd5-80b7-5a68c2b271ed" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
            </ns1:ErrorLogFileContent>
            <ns1:ExceptionLogFileName>exception-test_contact_01-02_20150422171310_pverma Data File.csv</ns1:ExceptionLogFileName>
            <ns1:ExceptionLogFileContent>
               <xop:Include href="cid:4aa55e1b-1d4d-48be-bdd0-66200de496ee" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/>
            </ns1:ExceptionLogFileContent>
            <ns1:BatchId xsi:nil="true"/>
         </ns2:result>
      </ns0:getImportActivityLogsResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

This response contains the flat files. I have to parse these files from above XML.
Please suggest any solution over it. Help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MSXML2` and `XPath`:

```
Dim xmldoc As Object
Dim xmlnode As Object
Set xmldoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
xmldoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath"
xmldoc.loadXML response '//The XML Response string 
For Each xmlnode In xmldoc.SelectNodes("//*[contains(name(),'LogFileName')]")
    Debug.Print xmlnode.Text
Next
```

For early binding reference Mictosoft XML v3.0 or v6.0.